# Building a chatting app using Agora in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, agora

I'am working on social media app and chatting, Audio & video calling I'am working on Agora. But I'am relatively new to this and can't find enough resources. Could anyone help me out with this as I'am not getting user_Id and Channel_Name and I'am stuck with building chatting features since I don't know how to proceed. Can anybody guide me on this.

This Error is shown while I'm trying to sign with User_Id :

> response :{"message":"no Route matched with those values"}
> E/flutter (30078): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Exception: Failed to create Agora account

Comment: What code generates that error? without that what do you expect?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [visit](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also read [how to provide minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .